# Angular-UI-Router: other stateConfig props/methods do not execute when resolve is defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the follow in my app.config's $stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider.state('foo', {
    url: '/foo',
    views: {
        'foo@': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/foo.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('foo.bar', {
    url: '/:collection',
    views: {
        'test@': {
            controllerProvider: function( $filter , $stateParams ) {
                var ctrlName = $filter('camelCase')($stateParams.collection,true)+'Ctrl';
                return ctrlName;
            },
            resolve: {
                data: function( $filter , $http , $stateParams ) {
                    var name = $filter('camelCase')($stateParams.collection, true);
                    return $http.get( name );
                }
            },
            templateUrl: function( $stateParams ) {
                var which = ($stateParams.id)? 'details' : 'listing';
                var path = '/partials/collection.' + which + '.html';
                return path;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If I comment out `resolve`, `controllerProvider` and `templateUrl` run and loads the template. If I don't, *resolve* runs just fine, but the others don't attempt to run. No console errors.

**Update** If I replace the functions of *controllerProvider* (becomes *controller*) and *templateUrl* with strings, it works.

Comment: please full config, or at least full **state** node

Comment: @EugeneP, updated the question with full $stateProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, I just realised my local copy of angular-ui-router was old. Updated to 0.2.8 (from 0.2.7) and all is well.